# Social networking website - What's the most performant way to implement a 'user search' in memory (no SQL)?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a social networking application in VB.NET, with a target userbase of 1-2 million users.

All user data will be in memory in a dictionary of 'User' objects with properties such as Country, Region, Age etc exposed. I need to perform search against multiple user properties in memory - I'm not using SQL.

What's the most performant way to implement a 'user search' against multiple properties?

**Additional Info**
I'm currently using UserID as the Key for the Dictionary, which is fine as most of the (non-search) lookups will be via UserID. I am considering using multiple Dictionaries as indexes using other User properties as keys, would this be workable? I'm really just trying to avoid an exhaustive itterative search of all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably LINQ to Objects, but I would use multiple dictionary lists if you're planning on a million users, especially if the properties of the User objects are able to change. (For example, all of the Users who's UserName starts with A go into one list, B-C into another, etc.)

Comment: I was under the impression that the HashTable implementation of Dictionary would handle 1M entries without performance problems? I may need to research this some more - it's really an aside to the search issue anyway.

Comment: I think the performance issues would come when many updates are trying to be made on some shared memory causing too many locks.  Separating it will make it so your whole user list doesn't need to be locked when an update is done.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It's quite a 'write-light' application, but this could indeed be a problem down the line.